# Iphone , Address info from address book

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I am looking for a way to get the address information of a contact from address book in iphone.

Is there a way?

Ta

Comment: dupulicate question at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558543/iphone-address-book-sample-code

Answer (score 1):

A while back I wrote a [short tutorial](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2009/01/21/cocoa-touch-tutorial-extract-address-book-address-values-on-iphone-os/) on the subject.